# What is the better way to write an update query if there is multiple choice selection for the data field to be updated?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

This is the sample query.

```
$test = DB::table('tesing')
->where('id', $id)               
->update(['a' => $a,'b'=>$b,'c'=>$c,'d'=>$d']);
```

E.g. when user is allow to choose whether want to just only update 'a' value or 'b' value and so on. How can i ensure that only update the field where selected by the user. There will be a checkbox which allow user to select which field to be updated. After that only specific field checked by the user will be updated.

```
$test = DB::table('tesing')
->where('id', $id)               
->update(['a' => $a']);
```

When user select 'a' field, then only 'a' field will be updated. 
Instead of using if-else statement, What way else can i use?

Comment: you have added column name to be updated as 'a', 'b' etc.  can you add your html code as well where you show the update form ?

Comment: @SagarGautam in html just a simple <input type="checkbox">

Comment: Then values at backend will be like this 'a' => 'on' ... or 'a' => '1' ?

Comment: @SagarGautam Yes, it doesn't related to html code, html code is used to check whether want to update the column or not. If i am using if-else statement then many condition need to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `a` `b` `c` are the column name, try with Eloquent:

```
public function name($id, Request $request)
{
    $test = App\Test::find($id);

    foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        $test->{$key} = $value;
    }

    $test->save();
}
```

Comment: I am not storing the value get from checkbox. the checkbox is used to prevent certain field to be updated. By default, all of my field will be updated, with check boxes users are allowed to select which field they want to update.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to create an array of the specific checkbox names that you are using which allow users to select which fields they wish to update.  Name the selection checkboxes to correspond to the updateable columns, and then only update based on the checkbox selectors and those the user wants to update from the incomming $request object.

Something like this peudo-code for columns (and correspondingly named form fields) "A", "B", "C":

```
public function update(Request $request, $routeModelBoundObjectToUpdate){

    $userCheckboxNames = ['ckA', 'ckB', 'ckC'];
    $updates = [];
    foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($key, $userCheckBoxNames) && $value == 'on')
            $updates[] = [substr($key, 2) => $request->get(substr($key, 2));
    }

    $routeModelBoundObjectToUpdate->update($updates);
}
```

Hope this helps.